# Ionic - How to request permission again after user rejected once?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

Currently, I can request permission for microphone with the following code if the user has not rejected granting permissions:

```
permission = await this.diagnostic.isMicrophoneAuthorized();
                if (!permission) {
                    permission = await this.diagnostic.requestMicrophoneAuthorization()
                    .then(async () => {
                        console.log('this.diagnostic.requestMicrophoneAuthorization succeed.');
                        return await this.diagnostic.isMicrophoneAuthorized();
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.error('this.diagnostic.requestMicrophoneAuthorization failed, error: ', err);
                        return false;
                    })
                }
```

But once they reject the request, the `requestMicrophoneAuthorization` is still triggered, but no dialog pop up and the result always returns false.

Is there a way to request the authorization again with Ionic 3?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need to use the `cordova-diagnostic-plugin` to check the current microphone authorization status and request authorization again if it has been denied.

```
import { Diagnostic } from '@ionic-native/diagnostic/ngx';

constructor(private diagnostic: Diagnostic) {}

    async requestMicrophoneAuthorization() {
// Check the current microphone authorization status
let authorizationStatus = await this.diagnostic.getMicrophoneAuthorizationStatus();
    if (authorizationStatus === this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS) {
    // If the authorization has been denied always, we need to ask the user to grant
    // microphone permission again.
    try {
    // Request microphone authorization
        authorizationStatus = await this.diagnostic.requestMicrophoneAuthorization();
    console.log('Microphone authorization status: ', authorizationStatus);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error requesting microphone authorization: ', error);
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: I think that's exactly what I tried. The function was called, but the permission-requesting dialog is not popping up again.

Comment: Once the user has denied your request you can’t show the system dialog again. You can detect the denied state and direct the user to your app settings where they can change their response

Comment: @Paulw11 Alright, can you post an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.